# IT Management Suite

Tags: information-management

I thought that finding a tool like this would be a no brainer - but it's apparently much harder than I imagined.

I am an IT Administrator for a small business (between 20-40 people) and quite frankly, we just want to find a tool or suite that helps us to manage the technical issues of day to day operations. Things like storing information on the employees and their workstations, sitemaps, internal support desk and ticketing, etc.

I have been searching around for days and am honestly coming up pretty dry. Helpdesk software is pretty common, but anything beyond that seems almost non-existent. Has anyone else had this experience, and found a workable solution other than ... just making a ton of Google Documents?

Comment: Back in my Administrator Days I used a wiki with tables for this.

Answer (score 2):

[Spiceworks](https://www.spiceworks.com) is the way to go! It can do helpdesk plus a bunch of other things such as asset management and monitoring.

Comment: It's free and financed via advertising. Is that advertising disturbing?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your supported platforms, so I will just assume Windows on desktop, and mostly Windows for servers.

BMC's TrackIT and "bigger brother" Remedy both have multiple modules besides the helpdesk/incident tracking modules that are all integrated. They are available (but not necessarily licensed) out-of-the-box. I have used both and I have had mixed experiences with both of them. But I have to say, they got the job done. TrackIT is pretty inexpensive for what you get, if I recall correctly. Remedy has some .NET APIs as well as some web service interfaces.

Also, you might try including the term "ITSM" (and/or "ITIL") in your search queries, as this is more or less conventional industry buzzword (also, you might want to tag your question with those as well, if you can get someone to create such a tag).